# White screen while running Ionic 3 app on Android

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

App doesnt go past splash screen and sometimes shows white screen after using command: 
`ionic cordova run android`
App works fine with command `ionic cordova run android -lcs` - but I need to test native calendar behavior.
I also created demo small aplication(Ionic 3 as well) using CLI with similar functionality and it works okay.

Thank you for any suggestions.

**Ionic info**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.13 (/home/jurr/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/jurr/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.18.0 (/home/jurr/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS                : Linux 5.3
```

**Cordova plugins**

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-market": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {}
    },
    "config": {
      "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with version of `cordova-android` I've set it manually to version `8.1.0` in package.json and in config.xml `<engine name="android" spec="^8.1.0" />` and it is running without any issue.